# Background color set using CSS does not cover last element of list

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage where i have a navigation bar where i am keeping the background for the nav elements as dark blue. However, it keeps on missing the last element in my nav list and does not makes its color as blue.

[image: Image looks like this:]

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="content_block">
<div id="nav_bar">
<ul style="margin:0px; padding:10px 0px;" >
<li ><a  href="x.html#C1">PATENTS</a></li>
<li ><a  href="x.html#C2"><span style="position:relative;left:9px;">TRADEMARKS</span></a></li>
<li ><a  href="x.html#C3"><span style="position:relative;left:18px;">IP LAW &amp; POLICY </span></a></li>
<li ><a  href="x.html#C4"><span style="position:relative;left:27px;">PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES</span></a></li>
<li ><a  href="x.html#C5"><span style="position:relative;left:36px;">INVENTORS</span></a></li>
<li ><a  href="x.html#C6"><span style="position:relative;left:45px;">NEWS &amp; NOTICES</span></a></li>
<li ><a  href="x.html#C7"><span style="position:relative;left:54px;">FAQs</span></a></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
#content_block{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
margin:10px 0px
border:2px;
padding:10px 0px;
height:400px;
width:1024px;
}

#text{
max-height:400px;
max-width:900px;
margin:10px;
padding:5px}


#nav_bar{
margin:0px;
border:0px;
position:relative;
width:1024px;
}

ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
}



li
{display:inline;
float:left;
background-color:#2E40AC;
color:#BAD2FF;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML and CSS are poorly written, unfortunately; the `span`s inside your `a`s (which is bad practice on its own) are misaligned.

Comment: @Abody97 Oh ok i got it.. i removed span from it and it works. but what must be the reason for span behaving this strangely ? i do not know if its written somewhere, span can not be nested inside anchors. please share links if you have. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've set background color to `li` elements but have text itself inside `span` element that is relatively positioned and being pushed by it's `left` property out of `li` element background color scope.

Rather then playing with `position:relative` and `left:value` you should achieve same thing using `margin` or `padding` property.

Once you have removed `span` add `padding:0px 10px;` property to `li` element.